# Is $\int_{|z|=2}\frac{z}{(z-3)^2}dz=0?$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have a question. What is 
$$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{z}{(z-3)^2}dz?$$
In my optinion it must be zero, because the singularity $3$ is outside $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<2\}$, is it correct?

Regards

Comment: Yes it is, you are right!

Comment: thanks. The background of this question is about the choice of the integration-path, but everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Since all singularities of $\frac{z}{(z-3)^2}$ are outside of $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|< 2\}$, the integral is zero.